# creating an array from another array using a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am Passing an Array into a for loop with an if statment, I am want to have all the elements that evaluate true be added to a new array. How Do I do This?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing that your ifs are the problem... ending them with a semicolon isn't the proper way to get what you wish. `if(block[l] == Blocks.air);` remove the `;`. Unless you actually want the code after them not to be run... kinda messy.

Comment: a maintenance nightmare...

Comment: that still won't achieve my original goal

Comment: Then what do you want?

Comment: What does it mean for an element of your array to "evaluate to true"?

Comment: if (x == 'correct value') { return true;

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau You are mistaking(I assume you made a hasty comment). an `if(...);`(terminated with a `;`) is redundant, since it's controlling nothing. Any code after those **WILL** run every time regardless of the condition.

Comment: @DimaMaligin Yeah, I tried to edit it to be more precise and I think I ended up doing the opposite. I still think his ifs were probably not written properly despite me not being correct in my statement of what happened :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have an object array, and you want to create a possibly smaller array containing the elements that satisfy some predicate, you are faced with the problem of knowing how big to make the new array.  You can determine that only by testing each starting element against the predicate, which you would normally prefer to avoid doing twice.  One way to approach the problem would be to use a `List` to temporarily hold the elements you want to collect:

```
MyElementType[] myArray = { /* ... */ };
MyElementType[] result;
List<MyElementType> temp = new ArrayList<MyElementType>();

for (MyElementType element : myArray) {
    if (passesMyTest(element)) {
        temp.add(element);
    }
}

result = temp.toArray(new MyElementType[0]);
```

Of course, it's usually easier to work directly with `List`s instead of with arrays, but sometimes you don't have that luxury.